# How to Configure Crashlytics alerts and Error rates in the Firebase Console

Tags: react-native, crashlytics, firebase-console

I need to Configure Crashlytics alerts and Error rates in the Firebase Console based on Crash rate threshold and Network error threshold and Critical errors approaching 1% or X amount in React native app. Tried adding onNewFatalIssuePublished cloud fucntion but it is not giving details about type of error and threshold. Is there any way.

Tried adding onNewFatalIssuePublished cloud fucntion but it is not giving details about type of error and threshold. Is there any way.